# onProgress loading for textures with Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi I am having some trouble generating a loading message when loading a texture for a scene. the onProgress console.log message is only fired when the texture has downloaded completely and not during.

```
manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();

manager.onProgress = function () {
    console.log('loading');
};
manager.onLoad = function () {
    console.log('loaded');
};
manager.onError = function () {
    console.log('there has been an error');
};

var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader( manager );
var planetTexture = textureLoader.load('/assets/images/planet/{{page.planet}}/{{page.planet}}.jpg');
```

I had a look through the examples but can't figure out how they are doing it in this example [obj loader](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html)

Comment: Its a Shame that `threejs` do not support bytes loader for `TextureLoader` class. You can see this in example code here https://threejs.org/docs/?q=loader#api/en/loaders/TextureLoader

Answer (score 1):

The `onLoad` callback will be called once for each item in the loader manager. So if you load one texture it will call once. You can see this in **[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/73uqes0f/4/)**.

To use the callback you can pass it as a second argument when calling the `load` method:

```
loader.load(
    url,
    onLoad
);
```

It means you cannot see the progress for an individual image, but merely for monitoring the progress when loading several textures with the same loader manager.

Comment: Hi I tried your code and i still has the same issue.

Comment: I think he wants progress on a single texture, as far as I can see, the LoadingManager only calls the progress function after each single item in the manager is complete.

Comment: Your jsfiddle still has the same issue. The console.log only shows up after the texture is loaded and not during the actual loading. I sort of figured it out myself in the end. In my scene I am only loading one texture onto one piece of geometry (a sphere) so what I have ended up doing is have a loading html element that is displayed on page load and hidden once the texture has loaded with the loading manager by getting javascript to hide the loading element inside manager.onLoad

Comment: @Wilt, they're right, progress on the transfer of individual files is not reported in your fiddle. Try loading a large file and you'll see users are notified when the full payload arrives, but they're not informed about progress on individual files...